# Why is my regex not matching a C and the next letter?

Tags: regex, unix

My testfile is:

```
PolicyChain:ComplementaryUser Caught
PolicyChain:SourceIP Caught
```

My regex is:

```
cat testfile | grep -E -o '[^PolicyChain:].+?'
```

It matches:

```
mplementaryUser Caught
SourceIP Caught
```

I'm ultimately just trying to match the string after the colon but before the space.  Please help??

Comment: Planning on using this in SQL... but just testing on cli for now. Don't think SQL has split function

Answer (score 5):

`[^PolicyChain:]` is a character class that matches one character that is NOT (as indicated by the `^`) among `P`,`o`,`l`,`i`,`c`,`y`,`C`,`h`,`a`,`i`,`n` or `:`.

Then you match one character or more characters, lazily `.+?`.

Since the regex has to start by matching a non-c (the first token), it cannot start matching at the `C` of `ComplementaryUser`.

I suggest that your decision to use a character class is an error, and you want a positive lookbehind instead, such as `(?<=^PolicyChain:)`: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html

A positive lookbehind means, 'look behind my current position and attempt to match this lookbehind regex. If it does match, we can continue with the rest of the main regex. If it does not match, we cannot continue.'

However note that lookaheads and lookbehinds are not POSIX-compliant, and you must use a perl-themed regex (PCRE) to have them. (Or .NET, Python, Java, Ruby...)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried cat testfile | grep -E -o '?<^PolicyChain:' but returns nothing... I'm on bash

Comment: I believe you meant `(?<=^PolicyChain:)`

Comment: @Asad Thanks, fixed. user1899415, read how the syntax of lookaheads and lookbehinds works - you must type it exactly right or it fails. (And you must be using a perl-style regular expression engine.)

Comment: @user1899415 You need to put `.+?` after it. `(?<=^PolicyChain:)` only matches the zero width *position* before which a match for `^PolicyChain:` is found, similarly to how `^` matches the zero width position at the start of the string.

Comment: @user1899415 Also, as Patashu mentions, you need to use the Perl style regex engine by passing the `P` flag.

Comment: Regarding your edit, `i` was already mentioned. It is a single character, there is no reason to mention it twice.

Comment: @Asad I tried: cat testfile | grep -o -P '?<=^PolicyChain:.+?'  and gives me "grep: nothing to repeat"

Comment: @user1899415 You missed the parentheses for the lookbehind this time.

Comment: Great! grep -o -P '(?<=^PolicyChain:).* ended up working.  the .+? could only match the first letter after PolicyChain:

Comment: But grep -o -P '(?<=^PolicyChain:).* matches everything until end of line.. is there a way to match just until the whitespace?

Comment: @user1899415 Yes, use `\S*` instead of `.*`. `\S` is the inversion of `\s` which matches all whitespace, so `\S` matches all non-whitespace. (I use http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html as my reference for all my regex needs)

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead.

```
cat testfile | sed -e "s/.*:\([^ ][^ ]*\).*/\1/"
```

Comment: what does the \1 at the end do?

Comment: \1 is the part of the string matched by the sub-pattern between \\( and \\)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use cut:

```
echo "PolicyChain:ComplementaryUser Caught" | cut -d: -f 2
```